# Query in MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, nosql

I am new in MongoDb. As I can see, if I want to do query there are two possibilities:
BasicDBObject object and Query object.
What is prefferable?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use BasicDBObject to add criterias  to your query against mongo database, just like you do with json document on mongo shell. 
Regarding "Query objects", I believe you are refering to QueryBuilder Class (ref: http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.11.0/com/mongodb/QueryBuilder.html).
It is used to build query in a high level way.

Regards,
Moacy

Answer (score 0):

i don't think it even exists a Query object. You should go with BasicDBObject to build your query. Give a look to the [java MongoDB tutorial](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Java+Tutorial) if you haven't done it yet.